# How can I verify AD replication between two DCs works

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

We have a domain with 3 DCs in different networks and we want to decomission one of them.

However, I suspect that the two remaining DCs will not replicate properly between each other due to some network misconfiguration. So I want to ensure that, after I switch off the obsolete DC, the two remaining ones will replicate flawlessly between each other.

I can ping between the two DCs without any problems, but I suspect replication might be a different story.

When I issue `repadmin /showrepl dc1`, it will only show the status of the previous replications *with the DC I want to remove*. The *safe* DC is not listed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried DCDIAG? It has lots of tests including Checks for timely replication and any replication errors between domain controllers

Here is a link to Dcdiag information:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731968(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @MichaelBrown you should have a look at Oliver's screen capture in his link ... Just saying, don't want to get into a fight with Big John...

Comment: DcDiag is better :) I want the points!

Comment: I run dcdiag /e after every patch. I wouldn't say it's a lifesaver, but I do sleep better when it comes up clean. Someday I'll script it to run automatically.

Answer (score 10):

To ensure two DCs replicate with each other, you can follow the guide [Forcing Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794809(v=ws.10).aspx).

You first want to ensure that both *clean* DCs replicate with each other.

1. Open **Active Directory Sites and Services**, navigate to your first DC and open the **NTDS Settings**.
2. You will probably see a connection to the old DC. Add a new connection for the new DC. Now force replication with your other DC.

   [image]

   Repeat the process for the other DC.
3. Now [inspect replication results](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794749) for your DCs:

   ```
   repadmin /showrepl dc1
   ```

Comment: DCDIAG is much better ;)

Comment: @MichaelBrown Running that actually pointed me towards an unrelated issue. So, definitely very helpful. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I went with this approach while waiting for `dcdiag` to finish and this gave me a very direct way to achieve what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the graphical utility MS has and checks all AD Forest for replication issues.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30005

Thank you

Comment: Neat tool. But it seems to expire pretty quick: https://i.imgur.com/otGlKja.png The link leads to the same page you linked.

Comment: That is weird I use this tool for very long time but never seen it expiring,  MS might changed something I will recheck it.

Comment: Yes as I suspected MS changed something in order the old version to expire. I assume soon they will update the site with 1.1 version that now their link points still to the wrong one.

Comment: I'll surely try this again in the future. Thanks :)